# How to build a navigation menu to be shared a cross the entire application with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter framework, what i am trying to build is a navigation menu shared a cross the entire application, the navigation menu it contains categories which will be pulled out from a database for instance

```
Home    +Products
         - Ham
         - Sausages
         - Etc 

1- I know how to pull this data from a database and i know how to make a navigation menu

2- What i don't know is, how to make this menu shared a cross the site, so when ever i choose product for instance i choosed Ham i will show all data from database according to ham.

3- I just need some help to guide me through this process..
```

thank you so much in advanced ....

Comment: you want this menu to appear in all the pages?

Comment: yes, that's correct.....

Answer (score 0):

create three files 
header.php,
your_page.php,
footer.php

Then place the

```
<head>...</head>
```

in the header.php

Then start the

```
   <body>
```

tag in the your_page.php and end the  in the footer.php

Here your_page.php is like your all the pages.
Now in your_page.php create a structure like below

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left_part">
         </div>
         <div id="right_part>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Now place your menu in the left part and apply the necessary CSS to it.

And in the Controller while loading any page you just change the middle portion

```
  $this->load->view('header.php');
  $this->load->view('your_page.php');// just change the pages you want to ...
  $this->load->view('footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a static, non changing menu, it is simple: create a CI View with the menu contents in it.

Let's say this view is called menu.php and let it's contents be:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Products
    <ul>
      <li>
        Sausages
      </li>
      <li>
        Ham
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Load the menu view from within your template view, in the place you want to call it from

for example,

template.php (this is also a view)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php $this->load->view('menu.php',$menudata); ?>
  <?php $this->load->view('content.php',$content); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can guess, content.php will contain the page, created, perhaps from the database.

Comment: this is not a static menu it's dynamic, do you think it will work for a dynamic menu?

Comment: Yes, You have to pass data to the view for that. I have made changes to my answer to reflect this.

Comment: See $menudata and $content also

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you; Of course you need to pass data to the template first from your controller, like $this->load->view('template',$data)

Comment: Was your problem solved in the end? If not, where did you get stuck? If yes, then you should select one answer as the best answer, if it actually did help you.

Comment: yes, bro, it has been solved out....i figured out that...i have forgot to use base_url() function ... thanks anyway for you help i really appropriated that